# Can't make a new application using aurelia au new

Tags: aurelia

When I use au new command in my mac terminal and give a name to my new app I am provided with  1. Default ESNext (Default), 2. Default TypeScript, 3. Custom. However, I don't seem to able to choose any of the options or type anything in the terminal. I am using aurelia 0.29.0. I added a screenshot from my terminal here: [Screen shot of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8pRU.png)

Comment: I realized when I choose the name in the same line of new au: new au contact_list, I am able to type in the next option, but then the next question will be locked!

Comment: I'm also having the same issue after upgrading node to v8.1.0 and npm to 5.0.3, (on linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I was facing the same issue on Ubuntu. I reverted back to node v6.11.0 and reinstalled aurelia-cli. This got it working.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue of NodeJS 8.1.0 which has been fixed in NodeJS 8.1.1. Two relevant issues:

- https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/645
- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13557